# Mac OSX 10.6 applications unable to store credentials in keychain

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keychain

For some reason, all applications are no longer able to store credentials in the login keychain. This applies to Mail, Echofon (twitter), iDisk/MobileMe.

I have run Keychain Access and created a new keychain, so I now have an empty login keychain. The keychain is unlocked. However, when I log in to an application, it does not create an entry in the keychain, and will prompt for password again next time I start the application.

I have run Keychain Access, Repair to no effect. I have run Disk Utility, Verify Disk and Repair Permissions to no effect.

Any pointers appreciated.

/Sten Vesterli

Comment: If I manually add an entry for e.g. Echofon to the new login keychain using Keychain Access, and then start Echofon, I can see that it actively DELETES the login entry. Very mysterious.